# Calculate gradient between n consecutive points for multiple groups

Tags: r

I have measured CO2 every 5 minutes in 400 rooms for a year so have a time.series for each one (see fig). I would like to try and find the gradient between n points for each room and return the value if it is negative gradient (every time this occurs). An example is highlighted in red below. In total there are about 100k measurements for each room.

[image]

Q: Summary: How can I find the gradient every 6 consecutive data points (representing 30 minutes or 6 measurements) which have a negative gradient?

So far for a single room I have done this:

```
require(dplyr)
```

**Update:**
Data is in long-format with room measurements stacked onto of each other.

```
n <- 100
dat <- expand.grid(t=seq(0, by=5, length.out=n), room_id=1:3)
dat <- cbind(dat, co2=runif(nrow(dat), 250, 2000))
```

test data with a single vector:
co2=c(100,200,150,99,78,50)

```
    check_6_negative<-function(pts){
      
      df<-data.frame(co2=pts,t=1:NROW(pts))
      lm(data=df,co2~t)$coefficients["t"]
    }
```

for a single set of points:

```
check_points(co2)
```

Splitting the data and using purrr::map_df

```
purrr::map_df(runif(60) %>% split(1:10),check_6_negative)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Assuming that the data is given by dat in the Note at the end this gives a long form data frame.

```
library(zoo)

grad <- function(x) cov(x, seq_along(x)) / var(seq_along(x))

dat |>
  read.zoo(split = "room_id") |>
  rollapplyr(6, grad) |>
  fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE, name = c(names(dat)[1:2], "grad")) |>
  subset(grad < 0) |>
  merge(dat, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE) |> 
  (\(x) x[order(x$room_id, x$t), ])()
```

**2)**  This could also be done with dplyr and zoo giving a long form data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# grad is from (1)
dat %>%
  group_by(room_id) %>%
  mutate(grad = rollapplyr(co2, 6, grad, fill = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  filter(grad < 0) %>%
  arrange(room_id, t)
```

### Note

Data in reproducible form:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
dat <- expand.grid(t=seq(0, by=5, length.out=n), room_id=1:3)
dat <- cbind(dat, co2=runif(nrow(dat), 250, 2000))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The data is in a data.frame, with the first n rows belong to room 1, then n+100k belong to room2, etc.

Comment: You're 100% right, I hadn't anticipated that.

Comment: Thank you for showing diversity, I'd never seen the 1st coding in R, that's really interesting! I'd come across the rollapplyr before for doing moving averages, so this makes logical sense. So I think I could do with removing the first few gradients after a +ve one just to make sure we're not calculating the gradient which includes points "either side of the spike/peak" if you know what I mean?

Comment: I am not clear on that but perhaps you could add a condition to grad such that if the 6 points don't satisfy it then it returns NA instead of the grad and then we could later eliminate the NA's or possibly do a second rollapplyr for that.

Comment: Hmm maybe filter using the lag of the co2 or crudely filter(lag(grad,2)>0) which would get rid of the gradients which had 2 positive gradients preceding it. What do you think?

Comment: `rollapply(grad > 0, list(-(1:2)), all, fill = TRUE)` returns TRUE for each grad for which the 2 prior are +ve.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` for continuous row-subdivision of data on 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, ... , (n - 3):n.

```
sapply(0:(nrow(x)/3)*3, function(i) lm(co2 ~ t, dat[1:3 + i, ])$coe[['t']])
```

Use this in `by` for multiple rooms:

```
res <- by(dat, dat$room_id, function(x) {
  sapply(0:(nrow(x)/3)*3, function(i) lm(co2 ~ t, x[1:3 + i, ])$coe[['t']])
  })
res
# dat$room_id: 1
# [1] -110.016639  -54.486543  -13.929304    2.458307  -82.666399 -143.942253
# [7]   75.081004  141.392661   53.859034  -12.203427  -61.160284   25.855611
# [13]  157.371771  -30.801235   69.006038  -55.579620 -111.569395   76.640292
# [19]  111.709559   60.051006   14.688974  -65.977536   73.835686  -17.511488
# [25]   -3.320638  -60.176528   11.759351   85.352167  -94.870994   37.666624
# [31]  -80.299898  -34.814470   71.907966          NA
# --------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   dat$room_id: 2
# [1]  -71.693656  100.391022  -35.716448  146.042504  -37.753200  -31.799380
# [7]  -44.696941   31.332556   34.920661  -41.662721  -47.622265  -62.573866
# [13]   -9.956829  -95.086073   47.155221   22.310729   74.507081   12.312134
# [19]  -85.876669  113.938713  -58.284926   -3.051781  -58.749569   39.509735
# [25]    2.352837   79.767429   21.640402 -105.589610   30.736577  -88.452255
# [31]  -11.515697  -13.292965   36.979825          NA
# --------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   dat$room_id: 3
# [1]   -5.80767286   -0.08253515 -125.17316486   68.28252505   20.10605063
# [6]  -84.94581481  -10.05121384  138.22122698   -1.16014878   10.53859907
# [11]   -8.22656194  137.69787288   81.90092078   24.51041857   83.80724086
# [16]  -58.17042933  -28.88227191   59.90420599   15.55485255   13.85182070
# [21]  -70.66571308 -141.83901612    9.76291233  -17.74572731   75.58558397
# [26]   11.73712306   -2.34267940  163.23427064   27.99664436    1.92079368
# [31]  -96.59437659  -51.91830711 -107.03973524            NA
```

You will need long format with room ID's.

To extract the values which are less than zero, use

```
lapply(res, function(x) x[x < 0])
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42) ; n <- 100
dat <- expand.grid(t=seq(0, by=5, length.out=n), room_id=1:3)
dat <- cbind(dat, co2=runif(nrow(dat), 250, 2000))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this calculate every 3 data points?

Comment: @HCAI Yes, the logic is `sapply(0:(100/3 - 1)*3, function(x) 1:3 + x)` which gives the 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, ... .  In the `x[1:3 + i, ]` you use the subsetted data. For a different time window, replace 3 with something else. Some `NA's` appear when these sequences won't add up to the number of rows, but shouldn't matter much since you just can remove them.